# Server side rendered authentication caching

Tags: javascript, asp.net, authentication

I'm rendering authentication data on the back-end within the layout cshtml. When a user is logged in and logs out and then clicks the back button (because the browser caches the page) the site renders with the outdated authentication status. This causes problems because the back-end thinks the user is logged out while the front-end doesn't meaning that protected API endpoints will get access denied.

Is there an elegant way to solve this issue without blanket forcing the browser to not cache pages or forcing the front-end to re-validate the authentication status through a dedicated endpoint on each page load?

I can provide code if needed but its really pretty straight-forward.